# TortoiseHG Sync - How to save URL

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've recently migrated to Mercurial for source control and am using TortoiseHG.  Everything is working great, but whenever I go to "Synchronize" to do a push, the remote repository URL is blank and I need to type it in every time.  How do I save it so that the remote repository source is saved?

Comment: Normally, after a clone of a remote repository the default push is saved correctly in the clone.  Did you originally create this repository locally and clone it to the remote location?

Comment: Yeah I was making a brand new Repo so I had to make it locally and then push to HG

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You did not mention which version of TortoiseHg, but there are two "standard" ways to save the URL:

1) Manually add the following lines to your `<project_dir>\.hg\hgrc` file:

```
[paths]
  default = http://server/path/to/remote/repo
```

2) Click the "Save" icon in TortoiseHg's Sync view:
[image: TortoiseHg Sync screenshot]

Comment: The `hgrc` syntax is wrong: there should not be any spaces before "default"